# Export varbinary to actual documents

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, download, export, bcp

I currently use SQL Server 2008 and have documents stored in VARBINARY(MAX) in the table

I need to be able to download all the files that are part of a select statement to a certain file location

Table Example

[image]

What is the fastest the way to be able to download 100's documents into a file location?

Comment: Anyone have any ideas?:)